# Is there a way to dynamically generate dataframes from another dataframe of indefinite row length?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am a rank amateur/beginner with Python, but am sort of stumped with this. What I have is a dataframe that is the result of an API query to live data. The complicated part is that this dataframe can result in just a few columns of data or many columns, and it is not something that can be predicted or hard coded for. Apologies for lack of code: the code I have to pull and reshape the data is all working well, but I am stumped here.

I have a df (called `data_wide`) that looks like this:

```
     Date         A1      B1      C1
0   2019-12-02  109.20  123.45  111.21 
1   2019-12-03  108.37  133.45  121.56
2   2019-12-05  109.32  154.11  131.34
3   2019-12-06  110.41  187.24  138.55
4   2019-12-09  110.79  201.32  132.42
```

And I need to figure out how to concatenate the columns dynamically, I think. I need the date, and each individual column to turn into a dataframe like so, ideally named after the header string.

```
     Date         A1     
0   2019-12-02  109.20  
1   2019-12-03  108.37  
2   2019-12-05  109.32  
3   2019-12-06  110.41  
4   2019-12-09  110.79
```

and

```
     Date        B1   
0   2019-12-02  123.45 
1   2019-12-03  133.45
2   2019-12-05  154.11
3   2019-12-06  187.24
4   2019-12-09  201.32
```

and

```
     Date         C1
0   2019-12-02  111.21 
1   2019-12-03  121.56
2   2019-12-05  131.34
3   2019-12-06  138.55
4   2019-12-09  132.42
```

But the issue is that

1. The initial dataframe has an indeterminate number of columns, since I am generating it by pulling data via an API and depending on the query there could be 5 columns or 30. Has anyone run across a use case like this before? I'm able to pull the first set manually:
2. The column names are going to be different for each API query I make, so those cannot be hard coded as text values.

```
test = data_wide.iloc[:, [0, 1]]
```

but I need to generate a dataframe for the date column AND each column that is generated by the API request. I feel like I should be able to increment the *second* iloc value with each loop of a for statement, but that doesn't seem possible.

Thanks to anyone who has some advice or insight on this!

Comment: `df[['Date', col_name_from_API]]`?

Comment: While the columns may differ, will `'Date'` always exist? If so, you may consider using that as your `Index` and then it becomes much easier to slice a single Series looping over `df.columns`

Comment: Date will always exist, columns and their names will vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
dfs = dict()
for col in data_wide.columns[1:]:
    dfs[col] = data_wide[['Date', col]]
```

Then, for example, `dfs['C1']` returns:

```
         Date      C1
0  2019-12-02  111.21
1  2019-12-03  121.56
2  2019-12-05  131.34
3  2019-12-06  138.55
4  2019-12-09  132.42
```

The same solution in a oneliner:

```
dfs = {k:v for (k,v) in [[col, data_wide[['Date', col]]] for col in data_wide.columns[1:]]}
```

Or create a list of dataframes

```
dfs = [data_wide[['Date', col]] for col in data_wide.columns[1:]]
```

Then, for example, `dfs[1]` returns:

```
         Date      B1
0  2019-12-02  123.45
1  2019-12-03  133.45
2  2019-12-05  154.11
3  2019-12-06  187.24
4  2019-12-09  201.32
```

Comment: This works! My only other challenge is how to rename the columns after the fact, but I think that is a far lesser challenge. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
frames = []

for col in datawide.drop("Date", axis=1).columns:
    frames.append(datawide[["Date", col]])

# 'frames' is a list with all resulting dataframes    
print(frames[0)]

# prints out to:
Date    A1
0   2019-12-02  109.20
1   2019-12-03  108.37
2   2019-12-05  109.32
3   2019-12-06  110.41
4   2019-12-09  110.79
```

This works regardless of where column `Date` is in your dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate this with a single dictionary comprehension:

```py
date_col = "Date"
dfs = {
   col: df.loc[:, [date_col, col]]
   for col in df.columns
   if col != date_col
}
```

Comment: Ah I had the same idea, just with `df.columns.difference(['Date']`. This is good because it wont break if Date isn't the first column :D

Comment: This seems to run without errors, but is it generating dataframes? I ran a ```%who_ls DataFrame ``` and don't see anything other than the ones I've created manually.

Comment: @jlgriffiths I assume `who_ls` only inspects the global namespace (and thus objects inside of containers aren't shown).  You can verify that these are all Dataframes by running: `[assert isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame) for df in dfs.values()]`.